# Making a column vector in wordpress blog using Latex

Tags: blog, latex

I am new to blogging and using latex here. I want to make a column vector as

[image: Screenshot of LaTeX output]

I can do this in regular latex platforms like overleaf.

But when I type

```
$latex h = \begin{bmatrix}

h_1 \\

h_2 \\

\vdots \\

h_n

\end{bmatrix}

$
```

in WordPress, nothing happens and I get the exact same output in the preview.

So, how do I make a column vector?

Comment: WordPress doesn't natively support Latex (AFAIK; please correct me if I'm wrong). You'll need to install a plugin to use Latex. [There are a number available, by the looks of it.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/latex/)

Comment: @PatJ is it possible to install plugins without upgrading to a Business Plan?

Comment: ...business plan? If you're asking about a WordPress.com installation, you'll have to check with their support. This site is meant for self-hosted WordPress installations. (That said, here's [WordPress.com's Latex support page](https://wordpress.com/support/latex/).)